# delphi multi thread cmd

Tags: multithreading, delphi, cmd

I have found this function on web which works very good

```
function GetDosOutput(CommandLine: string; Work: string = 'C:\'): string;
var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  WasOK: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  WorkDir: string;
  Handle: Boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  with SA do begin
    nLength := SizeOf(SA);
    bInheritHandle := True;
    lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  end;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);
  try
    with SI do
    begin
      FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
      cb := SizeOf(SI);
      dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
      wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
      hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // don't redirect stdin
      hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
      hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
    end;
    WorkDir := Work;
    Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CommandLine),
                            nil, nil, True, 0, nil,
                            PChar(WorkDir), SI, PI);
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
    if Handle then
      try
        repeat
          WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255, BytesRead, nil);
          if BytesRead > 0 then
          begin
            Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
            Result := Result + Buffer;
          end;
        until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
  end;
end;
```

The only problem is when I run GetDosOutput it runs third party application which is very heavy and my application takes too long and sometimes hangs
when i call this function from thread it does same take long to replay
any suggestion to make this function multithreaded ?

Comment: How could multi threading help?

Comment: I hate this code's decision to name the boolean success value Handle.

Comment: i dont care if it takes time just want exe to work normal not hang

Comment: So how would multi threading help? How would you split this single task into multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is the fact that the `WaitForSingleObject` call is apparently performed in the main thread thus blocking your GUI (at least that is what I understand from your problem).

So you could either:

- Wrap the code in the `.Execute` of a subclass of `TThread`.
- Replace the call with a `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`and when a Windows Message arrives use `Application.ProcessMessages`.

You get something like:

```
repeat   
  case MsgWaitForMultipleObjects( 1, PI.hProcess, False, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT ) of
    WAIT_OBJECT_0:     Break;
    WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: Application.ProcessMessages();
    else Break; // should never happen   
  end; 
until False;
```

Comment: This approach can lead to reentrancy problem.